# Installable webclip creation for mobile Devices

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, mdm, web-clips

I wanted to create a link on webpage so that whenever user clicks on link, it install the webclip with icon.I know there is option for that with Safari but I don't want users to do it manually.

Could you please let me know if there is way to do it for iOS & android devices.
I don't want to go for MDM solution.

Thank you

Comment: It certainly would depend upon the Web browser. If the browser I was using automatically dumped some icon on my home screen without my explicit permission, I would switch browsers rather quickly.

Comment: Could you please let me know for Safari on iOS devices

Comment: It is possible on iOS, but the user will have to install the profile (e.g. accept some prompts). It is not possible to have that happen silently. Not sure if that is possible via the link with Android.